# Storing constants in services in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Very begginer question, sorry about that!

I understand how to store constants in services with AngularJS, for example:

```
.value('baseUrl', 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/')
```

But how can I create another constant that uses another one?
It seems there is no DI in values ?!?

For example, If I want to create a `GetUsersUrl` which is `baseUrl`string + 'Users/' (concatenation)

I guess it's simple...but unable to find how to do it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store values in services, configure it in the run phase, and then access the values later. For example:

```
.factory('UrlService', function() {
  var UrlService = {};

  UrlService.baseUrl = undefined; // you can set a default value
  UrlService.getUsersUrl = function() { 
    if (UrlService.baseUrl === undefined) {
      return undefined;
    } else {
      return UrlService.baseUrl + '/Users/';
    }
  };

  return UrlService;
});
```

The run phase happens after config.

```
.run(function(UrlService) {
  UrlService.baseUrl = 'localhost:8001/api/v1';
});
```

Then, in your controllers, etc. you can inject UrlService and do

```
UrlService.getUsersUrl()
```

Edit: Rewrote the answer.

Edit 2: Another approach.

It also appears to me that you only really need `baseUrl` to be a constant. So, you could do:

```
.value('baseUrl', 'localhost:1337')
.factory('urlService', ['baseUrl', function(baseUrl) {
  return {
    getUsersUrl: function() { return baseUrl + '/users/'; },
    // OR
    usersUrl: baseUrl + '/users/' // it can also be a primitive value
  }
}]);
```

This approach works (and is more "the Angular way") if you do not need to actually configure the baseUrl. For example, if you can fill in the appropriate value of the baseUrl based on which environment (dev, production, etc) is running, you wouldn't need to configure it. Or, if the value is constant.